# Z shell constantly asks to correct 'rails' to 'tail'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zsh, rbenv

I'm working in Z shell with Ruby on Rails, using rbenv as the ruby version manager.

Whenever I try to run `rails s`, Z shell responds with:

```
    zsh: correct 'rails' to 'tail' [nyae]?
```

I have to press `n` every time for the server to start. It is likely that I installed rbenv wrong? How would I tell? If not, how can I fix this issue?

Edit 1: Here's what I have in `~/.zshrc` regarding **rbenv** setup:

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rbenv/bin"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
```

Comment: after you press `n` - rails works correctly?

Comment: yes, after I press `n` the rails server starts correctly

Comment: And if you enter `rehash` and try it again afterwards, does it still correct it in this way?

Comment: `rehash` does not solve the issue. There must be something wrong in `$PATH` or the rbenv gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is due to command autocorrection, set by the `CORRECT` or  `CORRECT_ALL`  options. You could either alias `rails s` like so:

```
alias railss='nocorrect rails s'
```

or add it to shell variable `CORRECT_IGNORE_FILE` and export it from your `zshrc`.

Another possibility is that zsh doesn't know about the `rails` command, which can happen if you just installed it. In that case `hash -rf` should help.

For more about both options see `man zshoptions`.

Comment: This worked - namely, using the `nocorrect` option. This has allowed my tmux startup script to just work without me having to go through and press `n` for each command that zshell wants to correct. I know it's not ideal solution, and I should figure out the deeper issue, but it's a pragmatic solution for the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `~/.zshrc`

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rbenv/bin"
```

Or simply run

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rbenv/bin"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue. See **Edit 1** in original post (after having tried your suggestion)